# Which yum group(s) contain a given package?

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

Is there a way to ask yum which group(s) contain a given package? I know how to ask what packages are in a given group, and could write a quick script to trawl over all of the groups, but it would be nice to have a simpler mechanism than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are only looking for a 'simpler mechanism' to be used by a human and don't need it in some kind of script or so, you might get by with this one:

```
yum groupinfo '*' | less +/sendmail-cf
```

Of course, replace `sendmail-cf` with the package name you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, yes just human usable is what I was looking for, so this fits the bill!

Answer (score 4):

You can find a group to which the specified package belongs, by using yum-list-data plugin.

```
$ sudo yum -y install yum-plugin-list-data

$ yum -C list-groups ftp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, list-data
==================== Available Packages ====================
Console internet tools      1 (100%)
list-groups done
```

Or, if you are not allowed to install the plugin, please save the following script and try to run it with one argument, the name of the package you try to find:

```
#!/bin/sh

search_name=$1
LANG=C yum grouplist -v | grep "^  " | awk -F'(' '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/^ *//' | while     read line
do
    if [ "${search_name}" != "" ]; then
        yum groupinfo "${line}" | grep -q "^ *${search_name}$"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo ${line}
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `yum`, but remember that it sits on top of `rpm`. The `rpm` command you're looking for is:

```
rpm -q --qf %{group} yourRPM
```

You might want to add a `\n` at the end, depending on that you are up to:

```
[root@Niflheim ~]# rpm -q --qf %{group} setarch
System Environment/Kernel[root@Niflheim ~]# rpm -q --qf "%{group}\n" setarch
System Environment/Kernel
[root@Niflheim ~]#
```

Comment: Interesting thought, but it does not return a group name that matches anything given by 'yum grouplist'